# Django app incorrect datetime during deployment

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

I have a django model with a datetime field like this:

```
date_creation = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Locally, on my machine, this control is created with the local date and time.
When the application is deployed the field is not created with local time.
I tried to do this:

```
date_creation = models.DateField(default=datetime.now())
```

It does not work. How to solve this problem ? I am in central Africa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass a *callable*, so you can pass the `now` function, or better the `now` function of Django's `timezone` utility:

```
from datetime import datetime

class MyModel(models.Model):
    date_creation = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
```

or with [**`timezone.now(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now):

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

class MyModel(models.Model):
    date_creation = models.DateField(default=now)
```

Probably it is however better to specify the timezone in the settings with:

```
# settings.py

USE_TZ = True
TIME_ZONE = 'Africa/Bangui'
```